# Difference between calling function and macro inside macro?

Tags: clojure, macros

My puzzle is the following example:

```
(defmacro macro1 [x]
  (println x))

(defn func1 [x]
  (println x))

(defmacro macro2 [x]
  `(macro1 ~x)
  (func1 x))

(defmacro macro3 [x]
  (func1 x)
  `(macro1 ~x))

(println "macro2")
(macro2 hello)

(println "macro3")
(macro3 hello)
```

Surprisingly, the output is:

```
macro2
hello
macro3
hello
hello
```

Why the output of macro2 and macro3 are different? In my understanding, all the calling of macro inside macro could be substituted with function (except for the reason of reuse). Anything wrong in my understanding?

---

Thanks Michael for clarifying. My general question is how to choose between using function or macro inside macro for the purpose of manipulating the s-expression. I wonder whether they can be used exchangeably except that they're evaled at different phases. Another example:

```
(defn manipulate-func [x]
  (list + x 1))

(defmacro manipulate-macro [x]
  (list + x 1))

(defmacro macro1 [x y]
  [(manipulate-func x) `(manipulate-macro ~y)])

(println (clojure.walk/macroexpand-all '(macro1 (+ 1 2) (+ 3 4))))
;; [(#<core$_PLUS_ clojure.core$_PLUS_@332b9f79> (+ 1 2) 1) (#<core$_PLUS_ clojure.core$_PLUS_@332b9f79> (+ 3 4) 1)]
```

Answer (score 7):

`macro2` doesn't call `macro1`. Look at its body:

```
`(macro1 ~x)
(func1 x)
```

The first line is syntax-quoted; its value is list structure of the form `(user/macro1 x-value)` (assuming `macro1` is defined in the `user` namespace; `x-value` here is the literal argument provided to `macro2`) and it has no side effects. Because there are no side effects and the value is discarded, this line has no effect.

---

Responding to the edit:

Firstly, it is important to distinguish *calling* another macro inside a macros body from *emitting a call* to another macro:

```
(defmacro some-macro []
  ...)

;; calls some-macro:
(defmacro example-1 []
  (some-macro))

;; emits a call to some-macro:
(defmacro example-2 []
  `(some-macro))
```

Secondly, in the case of calling functions and macros inside a macro's body, one must keep in mind what the relevant notions of runtime and compile time are:

- functions called by a macro will be called at the macro expander's runtime, which is compile time from the point of view of user code;
- macros called by a macro will be expanded when the macro body is compiled.

If a macro emits a call to another macro, the notions of runtime and compile time relevant to the emitted macro call will be the same as those relevant to the original macro call. If a macro calls another macro, they are shifted one step back, as it were.

To illustrate, let's consider a macro that delegates all its work to a helper function:

```
(defn emit-abc [abc-name [a b c]]
  `(def ~abc-name {:a ~a :b ~b :c ~c}))

(defmacro defabc [abc-name abc-vals]
  (emit-abc abc-name abc-vals))
```

From the REPL:

```
user> (defabc foo [1 2 3])
#'user/foo
user> foo
{:a 1, :c 3, :b 2}
```

If `emit-abc` were itself a macro, the above definition of `defabc` wouldn't even compile, because `emit-abc` would attempt to destructure the literal symbol `abc-vals`, throwing an `UnsupportedOperationException`.

Here's another example that makes it easier to explain what's happening:

```
(let [[a b c] [1 2 3]]
  (defabc foo [a b c]))
```

`defabc` receives the vector of the three literal symbols `a`, `b` and `c` as the second argument; it has no access to the runtime values `1`, `2` and `3`. It passes this exact vector of symbols to the function `emit-abc`, which is then able to reach into this vector and extract the symbols to produce the map `{:a a :b b :c c}`. This map becomes the expansion of the `defabc` call. At runtime `a`, `b` and `c` turn out to be bound to the values `1`, `2` and `three`, and so the map `{:a 1 :b 2 :c 3}` is produced.

Suppose we tried to write `emit-abc` as a macro with the same body (just changing `defn` to `defmacro` in its definition). Then we couldn't usefully call it from `defabc`, because we wouldn't have any way of conveying to it the actual values of the arguments to `defabc`. We could write

```
(emit-abc abc-name [(abc-vals 0) (abc-vals 1) (abc-vals 2)])
```

to make `defabc` compile, but this would end up emitting `abc-name` as the name of the Var being defined and include code for the vector literal `[a b c]` three times in the generated code. We could however emit a call to it:

```
`(emit-abc ~abc-name ~abc-vals)
```

This works as expected.

Comment: Thanks. So I have to use:

(defmacro macro2 [x]
    `(do
       (macro1 ~x)
       ~(func1 x)))

Comment: @M.Tong - That will cause whatever code fragment is associated with `x` to be printed at compile time, and the value of `x` to be printed whenever the code is actually run. Try wrapping it in a function like I suggested in my answer to test it out. I upvoted this answer because it's totally correct, but I hope the extra explanation in my answer helps too (although I admit I don't feel like I explained it as clearly as I'd have liked).

Comment: Thanks for you two guys. I edited my question and supplied an example. my question.

Comment: I updated my answer to respond to your edit. I think @DaoWen makes an excellent suggestion about using functions to test your macros to establish when precisely various side effects take place; you might even add some extra debug printouts (`(println "expanding macro1")` etc.) to make things clearer.

Comment: @MichałMarczyk Very helpful. Thanks. So in general calling a helper function is preferred than emitting another macro? (say I just want to de-compose the job of a macro).

Comment: I'd say they're simply useful for different purposes. Emitting a call to another macro is great when your macro implements a concept that can be defined in terms of another concept that is itself implemented by a macro; this occurs frequently in practice. Helper functions are great for decomposing the data processing logic of more complex macros into manageable pieces; this is no different to the use of functions in other contexts.

Answer (score 5):

I think you're confused about the difference between macros and functions.

- Macros are evaluated at *compile time*, and they take *code* as input and give *code* as output.
- Functions evaluate their results at *run time*, taking run-time *values* as input and returning run-time *values* as output.

The result of a macro should pretty much always be an [*s-expression*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-expression) representing the source code resulting form applying the macro. This is why macros usually use the syntax quote functionality, since it makes it easy to generate source code with inserted parameterized values via the `~` and `~@` escapes.

Defining a couple of functions might help you see how this works. Let's run the following code:

```
(defn testing-macro-2 [my-arg]
  (macro2 my-arg))

(testing-macro-2 "macro 2 test")

(defn testing-macro-3 [my-arg]
  (macro3 my-arg))

(testing-macro-3 "macro 3 test")
```

Here's what I get in my REPL:

```
user=>
(defn testing-macro-2 [my-arg]
  (macro2 my-arg))
my-arg
#'user/testing-macro-2
user=> (testing-macro-2 "macro 2 test")
nil
user=>
(defn testing-macro-3 [my-arg]
  (macro3 my-arg))
my-arg
my-arg
#'user/testing-macro-3
user=> (testing-macro-3 "macro 3 test")
nil
```

As you can see, `my-arg` is printed when *defining* the functions where the macros are invoked, not when I call the functions. This is because the macros are evaluated when the Clojure compiler is generating code for the function, so that's when the call to `println` happens.

However, if you use the syntax-quote in `macro1` to make it return *code* instead of calling `println`, which returns `nil`, then it all changes:

```
user=>
    (defmacro macro1 [x]
      `(println ~x))
#'user/macro1
user=>
    (defn func1 [x]
      (println x))
#'user/func1
user=>
    (defmacro macro2 [x]
      `(macro1 ~x)
      (func1 x))
#'user/macro2
user=>
    (defmacro macro3 [x]
      (func1 x)
      `(macro1 ~x))
#'user/macro3
user=>
    (defn testing-macro-2 [my-arg]
      (macro2 my-arg))
my-arg
#'user/testing-macro-2
user=> (testing-macro-2 "macro 2 test")
nil
    (defn testing-macro-3 [my-arg]
      (macro3 my-arg))
my-arg
#'user/testing-macro-3
user=> (testing-macro-3 "macro 3 test")
macro 3 test
nil
user=> (macro2 hello)
hello
nil
user=> (macro3 hello)
hello
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: hello in this context, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:107)
```

Each of the macros still prints the argument due to a `println` being called when the macro is evaluated, but since `macro3` now actually returns source code it actually works like `println`.

Note that `testing-macro-2` prints nothing because `macro2` throws away the result of the intermediate calculation `` `(macro1 ~x) `` and simply returns `nil` (the result of `println`). In other words, using `(macro2 foo)` is the same as just putting a `nil` literal in your code, except that the compiler will print `foo` as a side-effect when it evaluates the macro.

Invoking `(macro3 hello)` results in a `CompilerException` because the macro substitution results in the code `(println hello)`, but `hello` is not defined. If you do something like `(def hello "Hello there!")` then you won't get an error since it will find a binding for `hello`.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not satisfied with the answers so far, so let me take a stab...

The issue is that `defmacro` returns data that is then used as code.  Only the *last* expression in `defmacro` is returned and, in your example, is then evaluated as code.

So... in your call to `macro2` the following steps occur

1. `` `(macro1 ~x) `` is syntax quoted so it evaluates to `(macro1 hello)` and is *not* evaluated further because of the syntax quote.  This line effectively does nothing as a result.
2. `(func1 x)` executes inside the macro, prints the string, and the result `nil` is returned.
3. The result of calling `(macro2 hello)` is `nil` so nothing further occurs.

Later, you call `macro3` and the following steps occur

1. `(func1 x)` executes, prints `hello`, returns `nil`.  But since the macro is not finished this `nil` does nothing and the next expression is evaluated.
2. `` `(macro1 ~x) `` evaluates (just as before) to `(macro1 hello)` and is returned as code (it is not evaluated further, yet, because it is syntax quoted).  This is the return value of calling `macro3` since it is the last expression in the implicit `do` of `defmacro`.
3. The return value of calling `macro3` from the previous step is now evaluated.  It evaluates to `(println hello)`, but this is not evaluated yet.
4. Finally the previous steps result is evaluated and a second `hello` is printed.

I believe the point to understand is that a macro returns code to be executed and only the last expression is returned.  Perhaps also, remember that the syntax quote `` ` `` prevents the expression following it from being evaluated and instead creates a list in place that is not evaluated further (unless some other action is taken to evaluate the expression).

Yes there is a runtime/compile time difference between when code is evaluated, but for this question I don't think that is the key thing to notice.  The key thing to notice is that with `macro2` the result of calling `macro1` is not returned, but in `macro3` it is returned and is therefore evaluated further.