# How to correctly use valip predicate gt with macros?

Tags: clojure, macros, clojurescript

I'm working through Modern ClojureScript tutorial, and trying to write some macros to automate some things.

For instance, in one of validate functions:

```
(defn validate-shopping-form [quantity price tax discount]
  (validate {:quantity quantity :price price :tax tax :discount discount}

            ;; validate presence

            [:quantity present? "Quantity can't be empty"]
            [:price present? "Price can't be empty"]
            [:tax present? "Tax can't be empty"]
            [:discount present? "Discount can't be empty"]

            ;; validate type

            [:quantity integer-string? "Quantity has to be an integer number"]
            [:price decimal-string? "Price has to be a number"]
            [:tax decimal-string? "Tax has to be a number"]
            [:discount decimal-string? "Discount has to be a number"]

            ;; validate range

            [:quantity (gt 0) "Quantity can't be negative"]

            ;; other specific platform validations (not at the moment)

            ))
```

I've wrote some macros, but my function does not compile. And i don't understand why

```
(ns try-cljs.shopping.validators
  (:require [valip.core :refer [validate]]
            [valip.predicates :refer [present?
                                      integer-string?
                                      decimal-string?
                                      gt]]))

(defmacro empty-checks []
  `(list ~@(map (fn [x] [(keyword x) 'present? (str x " can't be empty")])
                ["quantity" "price" "tax" "discount"])))

(defmacro number-checks []
  `(list ~@(mapv (fn [x] [(keyword x) 'decimal-string? (str x " should be a number")])
                 ["price" "tax" "discount"])))

(defmacro quantity-checks []
 `(list [:quantity integer-string? "quantity should be an integer"]
        [:quantity (gt 0) "quantity should be positive"]))

(defmacro checks [] `(list ~@(empty-checks)
                           ~@(number-checks)
                           ~@(quantity-checks)))

(defn validate-shopping-form [quantity price tax discount]
  (apply validate {:quantity quantity :price price :tax tax :discount discount}
                  (checks)))
```

The error is: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching ctor found for class valip.predicates$gt$fn__2332`

And it is about `(gt 0)` form. But what does this mean and how can i fix the macros?

By the way. In the REPL expression

```
(apply validate {:quantity "10"} (concat (quantity-checks)))
```

works fine

Comment: what version of valip are you using? is this a .cljc file?

Comment: @nberger the version is 0.4.0-SNAPSHOT, ant the file is .cljc

Comment: Your checks macro evals the other macros in macro-expansion time. That's what the `~` in `checks` does. That's causing the error, because evaling `quantity-checks` makes `(gt 0)` to be evaled and that's your valip.predicates$gt$fn__2332. But you don't want that, you want to output `(gt 0)` to be eval'ed in runtime. I think you can fix it with something like `(concat (empty-checks) (number-checks) (quantity-checks))` instead of `(list ~@(empty-checks) ...)`

Comment: Or maybe it's just removing the three `~` in the checks macro

Comment: I've found some solution [gist](https://gist.github.com/mbakhterev/239ed1d89541025ca155). But it's quite ugly because of runtime `concat` call. But i still don't understand why the original code doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing to note is that you don't really need any macros for this. I assume that you want to use macros to learn about macros.

To try to explain the issue I am going to use a simplified version of your check function:

```
(defmacro checks [] `(list ~@(quantity-checks)))
```

When having issues with a macro, you need to compare what is the code that you want to generate vs what is the code that your macro is actually generating.

What you want to generate:

```
(clojure.core/list
 [:quantity valip.predicates/integer-string? "quantity should be an integer"]
 [:quantity (valip.predicates/gt 0) "quantity should be positive"])
```

To see what you are actually generating use `(clojure.pprint/pprint (macroexpand '(checks)))`:

```
(clojure.core/list
 [:quantity #object[valip.predicates$integer_string_QMARK_ 0x13272c8f "valip.predicates$integer_string_QMARK_@13272c8f"] "quantity should be an integer"]
 [:quantity #object[valip.predicates$gt$fn__25100 0x17fe6151 "valip.predicates$gt$fn__25100@17fe6151"] "quantity should be positive"])
```

That `#object[valip.predicates$gt$fn__25100...` gibberish is the toString representation of fn returned by `(gt 0)`.

So your macro is executing `(gt 0)` instead of returning the code that represents the call to `(gt 0)`. This is because `quantity-check` is a macro, so it is evaluated before compiling the `checks` macro. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20865271/difference-between-calling-function-and-macro-inside-macro) for a longer explanation.

To avoid the macro executing the function, you just need to quote the expression:

```
(defmacro quantity-checks []
  `(list [:quantity 'integer-string? "quantity should be an integer"]
         [:quantity '(gt 0) "quantity should be positive"]))
```

If you run macroexpand with this version, you will see that produces the same code as the one that we want.

Note that quantity-checks could be a function like:

```
(defn quantity-checks []
 `([:quantity integer-string? "quantity should be an integer"]
   [:quantity (gt 0) "quantity should be positive"]))
```

Back-quoting is not exclusive of macros.

Comment: could you clarify one more missunderstanding of mine, please? I've rewrote my validation code as here [gist](https://gist.github.com/mbakhterev/86c4ac21ced119a5e90c#file-my-validate-cljc). And it works as expected in Clojure, but ClojureScript gives error: `Don't know how to create ISeq from: clojure.lang.Symbol at file src/cljc/try_cljs/shopping/validators.cljc, line 30, column 32`. What is the problem?

Comment: what does Clojure println?

Comment: it just prints stuff with newline at the end. These lines with `println` can be commented out, but the error reemerges at line 31.